# Replacing an Observable Array with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

In our application we have a series of select filters that must be populated dynamically based on the context of the situation. On first load, the default options are inserted into the array via AJAX and it appears on the UI as expected. However, when the select list refreshes, the UI does not reflect the changes even though if you inspect the code the array appears to contain the new values.

I have written the same code for two filters but for some strange reason it only works in one of the situations, I have tried the following to resolve this to no avail:

- Populating the array manually using arbitrary data
- Forcing knockout to update with array.valueHasMutated()
- Using the two different types of array clearing functions array.removeAll and array([])
- Using push.apply and push
- Saving the result to a variable and then assigning that to the array
- Making the values inside the array observable

This first instance of the code works as expected when the options change:

```
     success: function (data) {
                      self.filtersModel.values2.removeAll();

                      var serverData = $.map(data, function (value, i) {
                               return new SelectBoxOption(value.Description, value.Id);
                      });

                      serverData.forEach(function (value) {
                               self.filtersModel.values2.push(value);
                      }); 
             }
```

This is the second function that does NOT work:

```
     success: function (data) {
                      self.filtersModel.values.removeAll();

                      var other;

                      var serverData = $.map(data, function (value, i) {
                               // If the option is "other" save it as a variable and add to array later
                               if (value.Code === "OTHR") {
                                        other = new SelectBoxOption(value.Description, value.Id);
                                        self.filtersModel.othersValue(value);
                               }
                               else if (value.Code == "EQTY") {
                                        var equity = new SelectBoxOption(value.Description, value.Id);
                                        self.filtersModel.equityValue(value);
                                        return equity;
                               }
                               else
                                        return new SelectBoxOption(value.Description, value.Id);
                      });

                      serverData.forEach(function (value) {
                               self.filtersModel.values.push(value);
                      });

                      // Add "other" option to bottom of the array
                      if (other)
                               self.filtersModel.values.push(other);
             }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

HTML to populate the select list occurs like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="value">Value</label>
    <select id="value" class="form-control" data-bind="value: selectedValue, options: values, optionsCaption: '-- ' + 'Select Value' + ' --', optionsValue: 'optionId', optionsText:  'optionName'"></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="value2">Value 2</label>
    <select id="value2" class="form-control" data-bind="enable: $parent.valueIsAuthorisedAndvalueIsEquityOrOther, value: selectedValue2, options: values2, optionsCaption: '-- ' + 'Select Value 2' + ' --', optionsValue: 'optionId', optionsText:  'optionName'"></select>
</div>
```

Example data is returned in this format:

```
data = [
    {optionId: 1, optionName: "Value 1"}, 
    {optionId: 2, optionName: "Value 2"},
    {optionId: 3, optionName: "Value 3"}, 
    {optionId: 4, optionName: "Value 4"}
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much deliberation, I found that the issue was not related to the ajax function at all but rather a buggy method call I defined before the changing the select list:

```
self.clearFilters = function() {
    self.filtersModel = new createFiltersModel();
}

function createFiltersModel() {
    return {
        values: ko.observableArray([])
    }
};
```

This created a new instance of the filtersModel every time the select list changed, so any changes to the model were lost when the ajax call was made. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the second code doesn't work because your are updating the `self.filtersModel.othersValue` and `self.filtersModel.equityValue` in every iteration.

I rewrote your code, hope it helps:

```
self.filtersModel.values.removeAll();

var normals = [];
var others = [];
var equities = [];

ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function (d) {
   if (d.Code === 'OTHR')
      others.push(new SelectBoxOption(d.Description, d.Id);
  else if (d.Code === 'EQTY')
      equities.push(new SelectBoxOption(d.Description, d.Id);
  else 
      normals.push(new SelectBoxOption(d.Description, d.Id);
});

self.filtersModel.values(normals.concat(equities).concat(others));
```

Comment: I've tried this and it does not work either. The strange this is that on first load, it appears to crash calling `self.filtersModel.values.removeAll();` as my breakpoints placed after it did not trigger. Also, calling this function does not populate the select box at all...

Comment: To use the `removeAll()` the property `self.filtersModel.values` must be an `observableArray()`. Provide a JSFiddle with your code, then I can help you